# Emacs + Auctex: pdflatex command not found on terminal

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm new to emacs and latex, in general. I'm trying to compile a basic latex file after having installed auctex on emacs. However, when I run `C-c C-c` on emacs (inside a terminal) I get `bash: pdflatex: command not found`.

Apparently only installing Auctex is not enough. What did I miss? What else do I need to do/install?

Thanks for your help and patience!
Have a great day! :D

Comment: You of course need to install a latex distribution. Latex and the chosen editor are independent of each other.

Comment: Interesting. So Auctex would be the editor in this case, and I would also need to install the compiler. Could you recommend a good distribution for Macs?

Comment: Auctex is an extension to the editor Emacs (which, I use myself). For Mac, install MacTeX, see tug.org/mactex. After installing, remember to update, for example using `sudo tlmgr update --all --self`

Comment: Grr, annoying interface `--all --self ` they are options

Comment: Thanks so much! I installed and it's now working! If you want to submit your comments as an answer to the question I will accept it.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé Mastering LaTeX and Emacs at the same time is really a challenge. I started with Lyx, later used Kile, an editor for LaTeX, and later changed to Emacs as editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common error: installing an editor, but forgetting to install the interpreter as well.

In this case MacTeX is the obvious choice.